# C++ set-up for Visual Studio Code not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So I am trying to code C++ on Visual Studio Code. I am following a tutorial from youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DIw02CaEusY&t=597s

When I get to 9:58 is where I loose track. He gets a message on his #include  that says **edit "InlcudePath" settings**

I am doing the exact same thing as him and mine doesn't work. I am not sure why. I will show screenshots of his video and my code. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks!

[This is the youtube video's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeO2R.png)

[This is my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLpWn.png)

Comment: No don't follow any youtube videos. Follow the [official document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) instead

Comment: VSCode is *not* beginner friendly. I'd recommend using either a plain text editor or a proper IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this official tutorial to setup your VSCode environment, which is always up-to-date:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

In short:

1. Open extension tab
2. Install "C/C++" extension.
3. Install compiler, depending on your OS:

   - Debian/Ubuntu: Install GCC using `sudo apt install build-essential`
   - Windows with BuildTools from Microsoft: Install `Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019` from here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16
   - Windows with MinGW: Install MinGW like in the video you provided.
   - macOS: Install XCode
4. Follow one of the tutorial to setup VSCode:

   - Windows with BuildTools from Microsoft: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc
   - Windows with MinGW: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw
   - macOS: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

VSCode, depending on your platform should automatically find the compiler you have installed. You can try also to restart VSCode if can't find any.

You should see `.vscode` directory in your project, 
VSCode will ask you if you want to create those files.